# Animate integer increasing and stop on particular number

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have a count, and I am using a cell with a badge. What I want is when I get this count, to set badge number to 0, then to animate the incrementing from 0 to some count.

Here is what I've tried, but didn't worked:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<=item.count; i++) {
     int64_t delayInSeconds = .1f;
     dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC);
     dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
           [UIView animateWithDuration:0.1f animations:^{
               cell.badgeString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",i];
           }];
           NSLog(@"%@",cell.badgeString);
     });
}
```

It doesn't animate. I'm doing this in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath`, and doing it before returning the cell so that's the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So there are several things that I would do differently...

You're right, cellForRow is the wrong place to do this.  Try to trigger the animation in willDisplayCell.  By trigger I mean, set the initial value, then start animating in the next run loop using [cell performSelector:@selector(startAnimation) withObject:nil afterDelay:0];
or something to that effect.

Also, calling dispatch in a for loop is a bad idea.  You can set up an animation block with a completion block that then triggers the same animation block, each time getting the new value from item.  You'll need to keep track of the current value somewhere.

You probably want a custom cell that has whatever object item is.  Set that in cellForRow.  Cancel your animations in prepareForReuse.  The animation code can go in a method on your custom cell, in my example above it's called startAnimation.

Comment: This is interesting, thanks. I didn't understand from where to call startAnimation. And I think it's better to create the animation in the view controller, because there is the count. Probably just call some method on the view controller on prepareForReuse.

Comment: That would require linking the cell to the view controller, and then the view controller explicitly handling calls from arbitrary cells, which if the cell doesn't have reference to part of the model, requires looking up the cell in the tableview and then duplicating some of your cellForRow code (This is just my assumption though you may have done something different with your implementation).  It's better to use the view controller to provide/manage a link from the view to the model if necessary (or just give it the count it needs).  Much cleaner than managing the animations of all the cells.

Answer (score 0):

That's because UI elements don't update until a loops completion, and using this method you don't have any control over how long the numbers actually take to increment.

One solution would be to use a NSTimer to call the function that incremented the label, but assuming you want to see the label increment quickly I wouldn't recommend running one for more than a couple seconds.